# Missing VPN Icon

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, vpn

My device is Asus Memopad 7 (ME176CX)

Since upgrading to Lollipop I no longer get a key icon on the bar when my VPN is connected.

I'm not sure if this is a Lollipop thing or a ZenUI thing?

Can I get the icon back? I like to see the visual confirmation that the VPN is active.

Comment: Which VPN service are you using?

Comment: Cactus VPN, PPTP

Comment: I have same issue on my Memopad 8 (Me581CL).
GS4 works fine. I conclude it is a ZenUI issue. br,
gautier